# States For Login Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, authentication, material-ui

I found this Material UI login page example and since it is pre-styled, I want to use this one. However, I can't figure out how to store username/password etc. If I use 'State' in the beginning, I get an error that state is not found.

How can I change the code to make it store values?

```
export default function LoginPage() {


  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a function component, use react-hooks ( [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) ). What you tried to do (state) is allowed only in class components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `state` is only available in class component. In functional component you have `useState` hook. You can use it as:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function LoginPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To save component state inside function component, use the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook:

```
export default function LoginPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const classes = useStyles();

  console.log('email is', email);
  console.log('password is', password);

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            value={email}
            onChange={e => {setEmail(e.target.value)}}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            value={password}
            onChange={e => {setPassword(e.target.value)}}
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]